# Can Selenium support Hibernate or Spring?

Tags: selenium-rc

we are plaining for automation testing for our Java web-application, in this application following things are used Hibernate, Spring , Oracle11gr2 ......

please any one can help me Selenium RC can support or not ?

thanks in advance 
Ravi

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is used for testing a web application's user interface. That means: manipulation of HTML and Javascript. Selenium knows nothing about server side technologies, and that includes Hibernate, Spring and Oracle.

Comment: @Ravi: you can upvote or accept an answer if you find it useful.